# Edge removal (in matlab)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, noise, edge-detection

I have a image which looks like this:

[image]

The (blue) background have the value zero, the the (red) ring has a "large" value (compared to the rest of the image). I want to plot only the orange part of the sample. However, due to the finite resolution of the image the edges still appear as show here:

[image]

As you can see specially the white regions (yes there are a few) above are hard to see due to all the noise from edges.

Is there a good algorithm (preferable in matlab) which can help me clean up these images?

Answer (score 3):

1. Find the binary mask for the ring
2. Dilate the mask a bit using `imdilate` and `strel`
3. Use the inverted mask to 'and out' the ring and the region around it